# Backendless - Persist Current User Login Information

Tags: android, backendless

I have two Activities. The first one checks if a user is currently logged in using the Backendless API....

```
    public void checkLogStatusOnSite(){
    AsyncCallback<Boolean> isValidLoginCallBack = new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(Boolean aBoolean) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boolean is: " + aBoolean, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boolean Error: " + backendlessFault, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };

    Backendless.UserService.isValidLogin(isValidLoginCallBack);
}
```

If they are, the 2nd Activity is launched. If they are not, then a Login Fragment is launched. The user types in their info and is brought to the 2nd Activity.

Everything works fine when I use the app once. It opens, the BackEndless API says that no user is logged in, I got to the Login Fragment, login, and get taken to the 2nd Activity.

My issue is, when I close the app and relaunch it, I get brought back to the login Fragment. Mind you, I never logged out of the application. Is there a way to persist a user's login? For example, If I launch the app after closing it, I simply get brought to the 2nd activity? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you init your app you want something like:

```
    String currentUserObjectId = Backendless.UserService.loggedInUser();

    if (currentUserObjectId != null && currentUserObjectId.length() > 0) {
        try {
            BackendlessDataQuery dataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
            dataQuery.setWhereClause("objectId = '" + currentUserObjectId + "'");

            Backendless.Persistence.of(BackendlessUser.class).find(dataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser>>() {
                @Override
                public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser> response) {
                    List<BackendlessUser> users = response.getCurrentPage();
                    if (users != null && users.size() > 0) {
                        BackendlessUser user = users.get(0);

                        try {
                            Backendless.UserService.setCurrentUser(user);
                        } catch (BackendlessException e) {
                            ...
                        }

                    ...
```